# Force link connector to be in one place on a cell in jointjs

Tags: jointjs

How can I make the link to stay connected to a cell or a port in 1 point?

If the port is a circle, when the cell is moved around, the link end connected to it moves across that circle.

I want to be able to make it stay at the same point - the center of the circle's edge.

Desired:

[image]

What is happening when I move the cell down:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested, I solved this with the following:

Using 2 shapes.

- port shape
- the magnet, this is a circle with radius 1 (making it a point)

portMarkup:

```
<g class="port port<%= id %>">
    <path class="port-body port-magnet"/>
    <path class="port-body port-shape"/>
    <text class="port-label"/>
</g>
```

and attributes:

```
'.outPorts .port-shape': {
    d: circleFromPath(5)
},
'.outPorts .port-magnet': {
    magnet: true
},
'.port-magnet': {
    visibility: 'hidden',
    d: circleFromPath(1),
    transform: 'translate(4, 1)'
}
```

The `circleFromPath()` id a custom function that takes a circle parameter and returns `SVG` of a circle with supplied radius produces by `path` (`CoffeeScript`:

```
circleFromPath = (r = 5) ->
        d = r * 2
        """
            M 0, 0
            m #{-r}, 0
            a #{r},#{r} 0 1,0 #{d},0
            a #{r},#{r} 0 1,0 #{-d},0
        """
```